# Change text color When something is Entered in text box

Tags: javascript

i have form that has multiple input text boxes, Which has got some text message in light color. When User Types something That text should Become Dark.
I got a jquery code which is working, but i cannot use that for multiple text boxes

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
        <style>
        input{color:grey}
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
<div class="formWrapper">
<form name=form>
<Input type="text" name="name1"  value="Eg : Flat-27,Block 4,Skyline" size="30">
</form>
</div>
<script>
$('input').focus(function(){
     if($(this).val() == this.defaultValue){$(this).val('');$(this).css("color","Red");}
}).blur(function(){
     if($(this).val() == ''){$(this).val(this.defaultValue);$(this).css("color","grey");}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post up source code and show us what is not working

Comment: Should it change color when the field is focussed or when something is entered regardless if focused or not?

Comment: use `onkeyup` event for textboxes.

Comment: @acme text should change color when text is entered.

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov Can you show some example

Comment: `$('input').keyup(function(){ if(this.value != '')$(this).css('color', 'blue'); });`

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov Can we use this code for multiple textboxes

Comment: @Sibu Yes, read a bit about jQuery selectors and about javascript in general.. We're here for helping and giving direction, but not for writing the whole code for you.

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov there seems to be some conflict with my other jquery scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
// jQuery 
$("input[type='text']").keyup(function(){

    if ($(this).val() !== ''){
        $(this).css('color', '#ff0000')
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', '#000000')
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LRzKF/

Comment: I integrated this on my page, But i think it is conflicting with other jquery scripts.

Comment: @Sibu Is the page anywhere I can view it? Is the script being called from within `$(document).ready(function(){...});`?